# Godot PGSGP Why can't I connect a function to the signal

Tags: google-signin, godot, gdscript, nakama

```
extends Node

var client : NakamaClient
var session : NakamaSession
var socket : NakamaSocket
var username = "example"
var play_service


func _ready():
    if Engine.has_singleton("GodotPlayGamesServices"):
        play_service = Engine.get_singleton("GodotPlayGamesServices")
        
        play_service.init(true, true, true, "id")
        play_service.connect("_on_sign_in_success", self, "ConnectToNakama")
        play_service.connect("_on_sign_in_failed", self, "_on_sign_in_failed")
    play_service.signIn()


func _on_sign_in_failed():
    pass
func ConnectToNakama(profile):
    client = Nakama.create_client('defaultkey', "ip", 7351,
    'http', 3, NakamaLogger.LOG_LEVEL.ERROR)
    var split = profile.split('"')
    var id = split[11]
    session = yield(client.authenticate_device_async(id, username), 'completed')
    if session.is_exception():
        print("connection has failed " + session.exception.message)
        return
    
    socket = Nakama.create_socket_from(client)
    yield(socket.connect_async(session), "completed")
    
    print("Connected!")
```

on

```
play_service.connect("_on_sign_in_success", self, "ConnectToNakama")
play_service.connect("_on_sign_in_failed", self, "_on_sign_in_failed")
```

altough I do succesfully sign in, the ConnectToNakama function is not running also when i write play_service.connect("_on_sign_in_success",self,(suggestions appear)) if i remove the

```
play_service.signIn()
```

the ConnectToNakama suggestion appears but the

```
func _on_sign_in_failed
```

suggestion still doesn't appear

and I can't sign in if i put the

```
play_service.signIn()
```

in another function what can I do? :c

> Godot 3.5.1 Stable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The few things I can identify:

1. `singIn` should be inside the `if` statement, here:

   ```
   func _ready():
       if Engine.has_singleton("GodotPlayGamesServices"):
           play_service = Engine.get_singleton("GodotPlayGamesServices")

           play_service.init(true, true, true, "id")
           play_service.connect("_on_sign_in_success", self, "ConnectToNakama")
           play_service.connect("_on_sign_in_failed", self, "_on_sign_in_failed")

           play_service.signIn() # <-
   ```

   That is because `play_service` would only be initialized if the execution entered the if statement.

   On a similar note: make sure the indentation is correct. You could not be getting the suggestions because of a syntax error, such as wrong indentation.
2. The "_on_sign_in_failed" signal passes an `int`. *I claim this based on the source code at [PGSGP](https://github.com/StudioAdriatic/PGSGP).* Thus you should declare the `_on_sign_in_failed` method with a parameter:

   ```
   func _on_sign_in_failed(status):
       pass
   ```

   I'm guessing that `ConnectToNakama` is not running because it is trying to call `_on_sign_in_failed` instead, but that is also failing because it is missing the parameter.
3. They should not be necessary, but these are the types for "_on_sign_in_failed":

   ```
   func _on_sign_in_failed(status:int) -> void:
       pass
   ```

   And for "_on_sign_in_success":

   ```
   func ConnectToNakama(profile:String) -> void:
       # …
   ```

Comment: thanks that did it. I get this error when trying to auth into my Nakama server "connection has failed Not Found " Do you know what could be the reason? thx :>

Comment: @Benjamin As far as I can tell that must be something wrong with the call to `create_client`. Double check the arguments.

Comment: i double checked but I cannot find anything wrong even after double checking i get this error:
DEBUG === Freeing request 1
01-15 22:52:00.542 20046 20263 I godot   : === Nakama : DEBUG === Request 1 returned response code: 404, RPC code: 5, error: Not Found
01-15 22:52:00.542 20046 20263 I godot   : connection has failed Not Found
it tries to create an account but  fails

Comment: @Benjamin So it is making requesting to the server over http a resource that the server says does not exist. These are the possibilities that come to mind: Either that is not the correct server, or the server is not a Nakama server, or the Nakama plugin version is not compatible with the server version.

Comment: the server I'm using is a Linux server with docker installed and when I go to the IP and port I put there, I go to the login panel so I don't think it is that. The server version is 3.14.0+e2df3a29 how do I check if it is compatible?

Comment: @Benjamin I have no idea. I would try different versions of the plugin. Or try reaching to the developers.